# Не получается передать объекты в массив

Tags: java

Почему нельзя передать объекты в массив подобным образом?

```
public class elem {
    private int num;
}
public class mas {
    public elem[] elemMas = new elem[3];
}
public class process {
    mas mOne = new mas();
    elem eOne = new elem();
    elem eTwo = new elem();
    elem eThree = new elem();
    mOne.elemMas[0] = eOne;
    mOne.elemMas[1] = eTwo;
    mOne.elemMas[2] = eThree;
}
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        process pOne = new process();
    }
}
```

В классе process компилятор ругается следующим образом:

```
process.java:6: error: ']' expected
  mOne.elemMas[0] = eOne;
               ^
process.java:6: error: ';' expected
  mOne.elemMas[0] = eOne;
                ^
process.java:6: error: illegal start of type
  mOne.elemMas[0] = eOne;
                  ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы присваиваете значения элементам массива в теле класса. В теле класса переменные могут только объявляться.

То, что вы хотите сделать, можно реализовать двумя способами:

**1) С помощью блока инициализации:**

```java
public class process {
    mas mOne = new mas();
    elem eOne = new elem();
    elem eTwo = new elem();
    elem eThree = new elem();
    {
        mOne.elemMas[0] = eOne;
        mOne.elemMas[1] = eTwo;
        mOne.elemMas[2] = eThree;
    }
}
```

**2) С помощью конструктора:**

```java
public class process {
    mas mOne = new mas();
    elem eOne = new elem();
    elem eTwo = new elem();
    elem eThree = new elem();
    process() {
        mOne.elemMas[0] = eOne;
        mOne.elemMas[1] = eTwo;
        mOne.elemMas[2] = eThree;
    }
}
```

---

Кстати, имена классов стоит писать с заглавной буквы.

Comment: Ну хоть бы написал, чем они отличаются...

Comment: Вы о том, что блок инициализации выполняется всегда, а конструктор может быть вызван разный? В данном вопросе никакой разницы нет.

Comment: Заработало! Спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

В теле класса не разрешены операции записи в массив, можно сделать это в конструкторе:

```
public class process {
  mas mOne = new mas();

  public process() {
    elem eOne = new elem();
    elem eTwo = new elem();
    elem eThree = new elem(); 

    mOne.elemMas[0] = eOne;
    mOne.elemMas[1] = eTwo;
    mOne.elemMas[2] = eThree;
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

может Вы хотели вот это: ,т.е. вернуть неизменяемый класс, с точно финально определенными экземплярами Elem в массиве?

```
public class mmm {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Process pOne = Process.getInstance();
        System.err.println("доступ к массиву например к length" + pOne.getMas().elemMas.length);
        for (int i=0; i<pOne.getMas().elemMas.length; i++){
            System.out.println("класс в массиве : " + i);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pOne.getMas().elemMas));
        }
    }
}

class Elem{
    private int num;

    public Elem(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Elem{" +
                "num=" + num +
                '}';
    }
}
class Mas{
    public Elem[] elemMas = new Elem[3];

    {
        Elem eOne = new Elem(1);
        Elem eTwo = new Elem(2);
        Elem eThree = new Elem(3);
        elemMas[0]=eOne;
        elemMas[1]=eTwo;
        elemMas[2]=eThree;
    }
}

class Process{
    private static Process process = new Process();
    private Mas mas;

    public Mas getMas() {
        return mas;
    }

    public static Process getInstance(){
        process.mas = new Mas();
        return process;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ:)